# Error On Oracle Function That Recursively Selects child elements of parent

Tags: sql, oracle, function, error-handling, recursive-query

I am trying to write an oracle function that takes in a parentID and returns me a "table" that recursively finds its child and child's child and so on.. Here is my code for it but whenever I try and create the function I get these errors :

[Error] Compilation (17: 10): ORA-00604 : error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

ORA-01422 : exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

ORA-06512

ORA-06512

And here is code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TAB_TableOfIDs IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RETURNCHILDIDS (pParentID NUMBER)
   RETURN TAB_TableOfIDs
AS
   ResultSet   TAB_TableOfIDs;

BEGIN

        WITH MY_VIEW (ID)
        AS (SELECT A.ID
              FROM MYTABLE A
             WHERE A.ID = pParentID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT E.ID
              FROM MYTABLE E
                   INNER JOIN MY_VIEW B
                      ON E.ParentID = B.ID)    
              select bulk collect into ResultSet  from MY_VIEW;      

     RETURN ResultSet;
END;
/
```

The interesting part is , the code just works fine in a normal SQL query editor but if you put it in a function it gives the error.. So what am I doing wrong? and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, other than a trivial syntax error where `select bulk collect ...` should be `select id bulk collect ...`.  I assume that's only a typo that's not the real problem.  Can you add some sample data that demonstrates the problem?  I see no reason why your code should not work.  You don't want to give up on bulk collect if you don't have to.

Comment: @jonearles thank you for your reply.I had my solution yesterday :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my solution :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RETURNCHILDIDS  (pParentID NUMBER)
   RETURN TAB_TableOfIDs
IS
   CURSOR c1
   IS
      WITH ALT_BIRIM (targetID, ID, parentID)
           AS (SELECT A.targetID, A.ID, A.PARENTID
                 FROM ENTKURUM A
                WHERE A.ID = (SELECT ID
                                             FROM ENTKURUM
                                            WHERE targetID = pParentID)
               UNION ALL
               SELECT E.targetID, E.ID, E.PARENTID
                 FROM ENTKURUM E
                      INNER JOIN ALT_BIRIM B
                         ON E.PARENTID = B.ID)
      SELECT targetID
        FROM alt_birim;


   ResultSet   TAB_TableOfIDs := NEW TAB_TableOfIDs ();
BEGIN
   FOR mrow IN c1
   LOOP
      ResultSet.EXTEND ();
      ResultSet (ResultSet.COUNT) := mrow.targetID;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN ResultSet;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

Rewrite your `SELECT INTO` statement so that only one row is returned.

OR

Create a cursor and retrieve each row if you are unsure of how many records you might retrieve.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RETURNCHILDIDS (pParentID IN NUMBER)
RETURN number
IS
   cnumber number;
CURSOR c1
   IS

[Your query]
...

BEGIN

   OPEN c1;
   FETCH c1 INTO cnumber;

CLOSE c1;

RETURN cnumber;

END;
```